# Can I tap a double oven and induction stove on a 60a breaker?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, oven, usa, cooktops

Context - I'm in Indiana (USA) replacing my existing gas cooktop with an induction cooktop.

My existing setup has 6 gauge wire running from the panel with a 60a breaker to a stove with a 7.2kW rating.

My new induction cooktop has a 9.6kW rating.

Based on Table 220.55 and using this calculator
(http://www.electriciancalculators.com/QSEFYsecureLVNHTX/calculators/rangecal_REV1.html) I get a combined rating of 11kW. This seems fine for the 60a breaker, except 210.19(A)(3) Exception 1, which states that I can only tap from a 50 amp circuit.

This leaves me with 3 options as I see it.

1. Install as is, assuming the 60a circuit also qualifies for the exception.
2. Downgrade the breaker from 60a to 50a at the panel. This should still fit the 11kW load.
3. Run a new circuit from the panel.

I'd prefer to do 1 if possible, but 2 should be pretty simple as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You'll have to downgrade the breaker

Because the tap conductor rule in NEC 210.19(A)(3) Exception 1 expressly includes the appliance lead wires, you'll have to go with Option 2 and replace the 60A breaker with a 50A breaker in order to make this work.  Thankfully, unless your panel is badly obsolete (Pushmatic) or dangerous (FPE, Zinsco), this shouldn't be a big deal at all.

Comment: Makes sense, but how is it allowed as is? Conceptually the existing double oven is a tap off the 60a circuit as well. Maybe the inspector didn’t notice during initial home inspection? (5 year old home, I bought it this year)

Comment: @JakePusateri -- yeah, that's just not something the inspector picked up on, since you're right -- the existing double oven's supply harness *is* a tap

Comment: Yeah, the #6 Romex is actually 55A wire (the next size lower in Romex, #8 is 40A so you're forced to #6 for 50A circuits).  So #6 could be used for a 55A circuit, and then the breaker would be 60A since 55A breakers are not made.  Confused yet? It confuses a lot of people, which is how things like this happen.  (if I am gracious lol).